# Multiple Class Applet

Tags: java, applet

Hi have the following classes for a java game that I have created:

```
Contents.class
Reader.class
Sokoban.class
```

Sokoban.class is my main class.

I'm using this applet code snippet to embed the game onto my website:

```
<applet code="Sokoban.class" width="350" height="350"></applet>
```

My classes are all in the same directory,  but I get a blank screen when I try to load the html file that has the applet code.

What am I missing here?

Comment: The first step : enable the display of the Java console to see the actual error, http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml

Answer (score 4):

[Compose jar file](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html) from your classes and specify jar file in applet section as `archive` attribute. Code attribute should point to the main class.

Here is the sample for applet, composed as `SokobanGame.jar`:

```
<applet code="Sokoban" 
        archive="SokobanGame.jar"
        width=350 height=350>
</applet>
```

Comment: While making a Jar file is good advice, I cannot see how it will fix anything that is broken in this instance.  Note also that the code attribute should be the FQN (`Sokoban`) rather than the file name (`Sokoban.class`).